# #1046 - No database selected on phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I get weird error, I know its an easy fix but I stuck with it for a while.

Whole .sql file: http://pastebin.com/BAYQG6Xh

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you click on the database before clicking on Import at the top, or add

```
use your_database_name;
```

to the top of your import file.

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'TYPE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1' at line 31

Comment: TYPE should be ENGINE

Comment: Exact same error? If you changed it to ENGINE=MyISAM, you should be getting a different error.

Comment: okay fixed problem was, I did `TYPE=MyISAM` i changed into `TYPE=ENGINE`, instead of `ENGINE=MyISAM`